# Why is this D3 drag not working?

Tags: d3.js, drag

I'm new to D3 and just started playing with it. I want to move a pre-created rect (or circle) through drag and drop. Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hemY/).

```
// Create the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 400);

// Add a background
svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 700)
  .attr("height", 400)
  .style("stroke", "#999999")
  .style("fill", "#F6F6F6")

svg.append("circle")
.attr({ cx: 50, cy: 50, r: 5, fill: "red" })
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.call(drag);

svg.append("rect")
.attr({ x: 20, y: 20, width: 10, height: 10, fill: "blue" })
.style("cursor", "pointer")
.call(drag);

// Define drag beavior
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", dragmove);

function dragmove(d) {
  var x = d3.event.x;
  var y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
}
```

Two questions:

1. How to make the drag move work?
2. Why is my rect not showing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5hemY/1/

Quick debugging led me to find that `drag` wasn't defined yet when you were trying to `.call()` it

Comment: ...and to preempt your next question, you need to set the origin accessor for the drag behaviour to avoid the jump: http://jsfiddle.net/5hemY/2/

Comment: @Lars Your origin does address the initial jumping. However, the dot jumps on following clicks. Is there a quick fix?

Comment: Ooops, well spotted, should have been the translation: http://jsfiddle.net/5hemY/3/

Comment: Excellent Lars, I was really wondering how to do this efficiently (even tho i answered this question!)

Comment: in d3 version 4 origin is not provided how to solve jump issue?

Comment: @chiranjeevigk Write a new question for this, please! You can link it back here to get these people to look at it.